# How is WCF service connected to endpoints by default?

Tags: wcf

I have been provided a code base where a WCF service is hosted in IIS. The project uses development server, but that does not matter. 
The web.config file contains only the following section for service configuration:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The .svc file contains the following:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TestApp.MySvcClass" CodeBehind="MySvcClass.svc.cs" %>
```

MySvcClass implements the contract (ISvcContract). 
The thing is, under .NET 4, this configuration works. There is no declaration anywhere that establishes the link between the contract and the service types, there is nothing that links the behaviors to service type, there is no end point declaration, and yet it works.
With .net 3.5, it does not. It complains about the configuration.

What is the default behavior for WCF service projects' configuration? 
Where is it documented? 
Can I force these type of settings to fail?

I did not have the time to test, but if I add another svc file, the project would probably go crazy, since things may magically fall into place for a single service, but I'd rather not have configuration processed in a smart way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)

Read the *Simplified Configuration* section. It lists out default endpoints, protocols, bindings, etc.